# react prevent child update from parent container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a [react color picker](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color) that changes the state on change (so many times per second). since the state changes my component, and all of its children are being rerendered. **I don't have any control over the children** as they're imported from other libraries (reactstrap and react-fontawesome) so I need a way to prevent these from updating from the parent containers.

I could create a wrapper component with a custom `shouldComponentUpdate()` but that solution seems kind of hacky so I'm curious if there's an intended solution for this.

relevant parts of my code:

```
//all components come from libraries so I have no control over them
    <SketchPicker
       color={this.state.color}
       onChange={this.handleChangeColor}
    />

  handleChangeColor = color => {
    this.setState({ color: color.rgb });
  };

//rest of the code is made of multiple
 <NavItem>
  <NavLink ... >
    <FontAwesomeIcon ... />
  </NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

some of my navItems rely on the real time color information but most of them dont

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` is not hacky at all

Comment: Are the child components class-based or functional?

Comment: @KenoClayton but I can't access the components so I'd have to create wrappers for all of them

Comment: I see what you mean. However are the rerenders affecting performance for those components?

Comment: @KenoClayton yes. The rerenders occur basically on mouse move so I have up to 100 renders in a ms

Comment: You could consider delaying those updates until the mouse stops moving. Have some kind of setTimeout that can be interrupted if the mouse moves again within that time. However, if that's not an option, you could try using React.memo https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo to wrap them.

Comment: @KenoClayton I need the color information in real time, I'll try the memoization though!

Answer (score 1):

If the props you're passing down are not changing you can indeed use `shouldComponentUpdate` or even better `React.PureComponent`. PureComponent children won't re-render if the props passed from top level are the same as the previous props. The comparison is shallow so it wouldn't work for deeply nested props.

Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

Comment: I don't have access to the child components. I'd have to wrap all of them individually.

Comment: added a relevant snippet to my question

Comment: Can you try wrapping them all in a React.PureComponent and then render that component under this line `// rest of the code is made of multiple`?

Comment: > I could create a wrapper component with a custom shouldComponentUpdate() but that solution seems kind of hacky so I'm curious if there's an intended solution for this. (from my original question)

Comment: This is exactly what you need, it's not hacky it'e the default and documented way of React to prevent unneeded re-render.

Comment: It is what I would do if I had control over my child components but don't so I have to create an extra component to wrap my children in just to check if they should update. I posted this question because I'm looking for a more Ideal solution that allows me to do this from the parent container

Answer (score 0):

I you use redux you can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).
A selector (props essentially) is not recomputed unless one of its arguments changes.